# Split a string at uppercase characters and numbers ignoring consecutive uppercase letters in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to split a string in python based on uppercase characters and numbers ignoring consecutive uppercase letters.

For example,
`ThisIs9ATestStringABC95` should look like
`This Is 9 A Test String ABC 95`.

I tried to do a search with regular expression using the formula

```
val = re.findall(r'[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*(?![a-z])|[a-z]*)', `ThisIs9ATestStringABC95` )
```

but it is ignoring the numbers

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d+|[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*(?![a-z])|[a-z]*)', 'ThisIs9ATestStringABC95')` ??

Comment: If you can write it as an answer I will upvote it and make it the answer to this question. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually looking for digits in your expression.
So you could specify like this or like Johhny Mopp mentions with `\d`

```
val = re.findall(r'[0-9]+|[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*(?![a-z])|[a-z]*)', 'ThisIs9ATestStringABC95' )
```